# Proxy server error in git

Tags: git, proxy

I'm trying to clone a repository, but i keep getting the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/amberm291/funkme/': Failed to connect to 202.141.80.19 port 3128: Connection timed out
```

On googling a little further i tried to unset the http.proxy and https.proxy in my system. Also i ran the following command:

```
git config --global -l
```

It gave the following output:

```
user.email=ambermadvariya@gmail.com
user.name=amberm291
```

I don't see any proxy variable in this output. Also my http_proxy environment variable in linux is set to none. I'm not sure what is the problem. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What `git config -l` returns? (There is more congit than just the global one)

Comment: Do you have environment variables like `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY`?

Answer (score 1):

You have configured git to use proxy.

But that proxy is not active ( running ) since you are at your home not at IITG.

So clear your environment variables(both http_proxy and https_proxy) and proxy settings and it will work.

Try

```
$echo $http_proxy
$echo $https_proxy
```

to check the values of these variables just before cloning the repo.

Commands to unset proxy for git ( if you have configured )

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

-- 
Harshil Lodhi